# What does capturing a liquid variable then assigning to nil do?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, jekyll-bootstrap

Jekyll bootstrap includes the file `_includes/JB/setup`:

```
{% capture jbcache %}
  <!--
  - Dynamically set liquid variables for working with URLs/paths
  -->
  {% if site.JB.setup.provider == "custom" %}
    {% include custom/setup %}
  {% else %}
    {% if site.safe and site.JB.BASE_PATH and site.JB.BASE_PATH != '' %}
      {% assign BASE_PATH = site.JB.BASE_PATH %}
      {% assign HOME_PATH = site.JB.BASE_PATH %}
    {% else %}
      {% assign BASE_PATH = nil %}
      {% assign HOME_PATH = "/" %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if site.JB.ASSET_PATH %}
      {% assign ASSET_PATH = site.JB.ASSET_PATH %}
    {% else %}
      {% capture ASSET_PATH %}{{ BASE_PATH }}/assets/themes/{{ page.theme.name }}{% endcapture %}
    {% endif %}  
  {% endif %}
{% endcapture %}{% assign jbcache = nil %}
```

I understand that this 1) captures the text as a variable then 2) assigns it to nil immediately, effectively throwing it away.  So what does this do?

Answer (score 3):

Because you want the side-effects of rendering but don't want the rendered output.  If you *don't* capture, the rendered content is output.  But you don't actually want the output, so you throw it away when you're done.  It's a slight hack.

So if you want to compute without outputting the result, capturing in a variable is a reasonable thing to do.  The "then assign to nil" hack is a way of saying we are interested in the side-effects of the rendering computation, not the output.  Those other `assign`ments persist have effects that persist even when the variable is thrown out.

The `{%include custom/setup %}`'s output will similarly be thrown away, but its side-effects may be important.