# Why should I put {% include JB/setup %} in each post in Jekyll bootstrap?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I am using [Jekyll Bootstrap](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/). And I can post an article, however I don't know why post template put `{% include JB/setup %}` in each post markdown file. I have little knowledge about ruby and Jekyll. But I check some document and I can understand some codes. But I still don't know what this means:

```
{% capture jbcache %}
  <!--
  - Dynamically set liquid variables for working with URLs/paths
  -->
  {% if site.JB.setup.provider == "custom" %}
    {% include custom/setup %}
  {% else %}
    {% if site.safe and site.JB.BASE_PATH and site.JB.BASE_PATH != '' %}
      {% assign BASE_PATH = site.JB.BASE_PATH %}
      {% assign HOME_PATH = site.JB.BASE_PATH %}
    {% else %}
      {% assign BASE_PATH = nil %}
      {% assign HOME_PATH = "/" %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if site.JB.ASSET_PATH %}
      {% assign ASSET_PATH = site.JB.ASSET_PATH %}
    {% else %}
      {% capture ASSET_PATH %}{{ BASE_PATH }}/assets/themes/{{ page.theme.name }}{% endcapture %}
    {% endif %}  
  {% endif %}
{% endcapture %}{% assign jbcache = nil %}
```

I have checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499938/what-does-capturing-a-liquid-variable-then-assigning-to-nil-do). I am still confused. So this is my question:

1. Why should I put {% include JB/setup %} in each post in Jekyll bootstrap?
2. Can I modify template to remove {% include JB/setup %} in each post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using command `rake post title="new post name"`.

See Rakefile [here](https://github.com/plusjade/jekyll-bootstrap/blob/master/Rakefile#L72):

```
puts "Creating new post: #{filename}"
open(filename, 'w') do |post|
  post.puts "---"
  post.puts "layout: post"
  post.puts "title: \"#{title.gsub(/-/,' ')}\""
  post.puts 'description: ""'
  post.puts "category: #{category}"
  post.puts "tags: #{tags}"
  post.puts "---"
  post.puts "{% include JB/setup %}"
end
```

Removing line `post.puts "{% include JB/setup %}"` will do the trick.

Comment: However, if I remove that line. There is no CSS style and navigation.

Comment: @einverne: I can't see anything wrong with it. CSS and navigation have been rendered correctly. For example, remove `{% include JB/setup %}` from any of your existing posts.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to put than line in each markdown file.  So is there any way to remove that line.

Comment: @einverne: Like I said, remove `post.puts "{% include JB/setup %}"` from Rakfile. For existing posts, please do it manually.

Comment: After I remove that line. Everything on my site went wrong.

Comment: @einverne: That's just a Rakefile. Nothing could possibly go wrong. Please state which line you have deleted (for example, line 72 of your `einverne.github.io/Rakefile`)

Comment: Thanks. I checked it again. It's OK.

Answer (score 0):

That's because JB/setup file setup variables like `BASE_PATH`, `ASSET_PATH`;
Suppose a scenario:In your template file or html file, you have the following code
    
then you will occur errors.
That's because you get an incorrect value for `ASSET_PATH`;
If you are using [Jekyll Bootstraps](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/) like I do,you will find some comments in file "root_directory"/_config.yml for your better understanding:

```
# By default, the asset_path is automatically defined relative to BASE_PATH plus the enabled theme.
# ex: [BASE_PATH]/assets/themes/[THEME-NAME]
#
# Override this by defining an absolute path to assets here.
# ex:
#   http://s3.amazonaws.com/yoursite/themes/watermelon
#   /assets
#
ASSET_PATH : false
```

Answer (score 0):

not exactly.

While this seems true, it never sets, even at the base layout, using asset-path or similar tags never works for me. Id advise removing it. And adding in '/' as it says, and I have bugged, is incorrect. './' is more correct but jekyll doesnt seem to see the dots. (you are pointing to the root of a linux drive, where the files simply are not)

thank you for the clarification. the existance of it is moot, it was added in during theme 'installation' which is really a waste.

you only need the layouts folder and "theme_packs" if you want more than one theme available. otherwise, just the layouts folder. The includes are for JB, which, as noted here is moot to exist in the first place.

The only instance you need bootstrap(and this is NOT correct in implementation in jekyll) is for lets say a menu.

bootstrap
css file
javascript file

no connection what-so-ever to jekyll.You have to implement this yourself.